# Variable does not exist: Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Could you please let me know what i am doing here here, it would be a silly question for most of them sorry, I am actually completely new to this development so

```
trigger AccountContactAddressUpdate on Account (after update) {
    switch on Trigger.operationType(){ 
        when AFTER_UPDATE(){
       
    }
        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `operationType()` as a method by including the parentheses, but it is an attribute.

**Incorrect**

```
switch on Trigger.operationType()
```

**Correct**

```
switch on Trigger.operationType
```